# Heat equation with boundary condition paradox

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A uniform, heat conductive sphere of radius $\rho$ is perfectly insulated and is heated by a uniform, internal (and constant) heat source $q$.

The PDE is:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)\right)+q$$

where $T$ is temperature, $r$ is the radial coordinate and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity.

Developed and using PDE shorthand:

$$T_t=\alpha \frac{T_{r}}{r}+\alpha T_{rr}+q$$

Perfect insulation, using Fourier's first law:

$$T_r(\rho,t)=0$$

Initial ($t=0$) radial temperature distribution:

$$T(r,0)=f(r)$$

---

We attempt to solve it with:

$$T(r,t)=T_E(r)+T_p(r,t)$$

where $T_E$ is the steady state solution and $T_P$ is a particular solution. Both need to satisfy the original PDE and its BC/IC.

For the steady state solution we have:
$$\alpha \frac{T_{r}}{r}+\alpha T_{rr}+q=0$$
Slightly restated:
$$\alpha rT''(r)+\alpha T'(r)+qr=0$$
This solves to:
$$T(r)=c_1\ln r +c_2-\frac{qr^2}{4\alpha}$$
And here's the rub. For:
$$r \to 0\text{ then } T(r) \to -\infty \Rightarrow c_1=0$$
So $c_1$ must be $0$.

But this causes a problem, because:
$$T_r(\rho,t)=0 \Rightarrow T'(\rho)=0$$
and $c_2$ drops out...

I've a feeling I'll be having lots of egg on my face when this conundrum will be resolved but right now I can't see what's causing the problem?

Comment: Is $q = C$, $q = q(r)$ or $q = q(r,t)$?

Comment: $q=\text{constant}$. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something. Are you saying that you have a perfectly insulated sphere with an internal heat source? Just my two cents, but it doesn't seem to me that this *should* have a steady state solution. Shouldn't the temperature just continute to increase indefinitely, regardless of the time that has passed?

Comment: @user20672 Ah. I think you've nailed it. I need to change that BC. Put your comment in as an answer and grab that bounty! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure no steady-state solution exists to this problem unless $q=0$. A perfectly insulated sphere with a constant internal heat source will only ever get hotter, no matter how much time has passed.